MAUI Binding to default interface property
In my MAUI sample project I have an IGrid interface with a default implemented string property:
public interface IGrid
{
  string TestName => "IGrid.TestName";
}

A Grid class implementing it :
internal class Grid : IGrid
{}

My XAML binding :
<ListView
    x:Name="GridsList"
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyGrids}"
    BackgroundColor="DarkRed">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell
                Text="{Binding Path=(local:IGrid.TestName)}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>

with this code behind :
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
 {
   private ObservableCollection<IGrid> _myGrids = new ObservableCollection<IGrid>();
   public ObservableCollection<IGrid> MyGrids => _myGrids;
   /// ... 
   /// Omitted populating _myGrids
   /// ...
 }

I thought reading this using {Binding Path=(local:IGrid.TestName)} would do the trick, but the binding fail at runtime with :

'(local:IGrid' property not found on 'TestDTOPackageMAUI.Sources.Business.POCO.Grid', target property: 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.TextCell.Text'

I do understand that from Grid object point of view, there is no access to TestName property. We would have to cast it to IGrid first in C#.
That what I expected with {Binding Path=(local:IGrid.TestName)} in XAML, but appently not.
Is that impossible this way ? If so does using a Converter would be a good solution ?

AFAIK you can’t bind to an interface
