Converter behavior miss first item in a CollectionView updating items
Disclaimer : I know this is not respecting MVVM pattern, I twisted it on purpose to reflect in UI while testing/ debugging.
To brief things up, I have a first CollectionView bind to an ObservableCollection<MyStringVM> (my view model representation of my model) via an Entry (input text box) for each item.
I have a second CollectionView bind to an DeepObservableCollection<MyString> directly to my model to check visually in UI if all change are propagated as intended in my model (this is were I twist MVVM pattern). :
View XAML
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TestingDeepRefresh.MainPage"
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:TestingDeepRefresh.Sources.Models"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:TestingDeepRefresh.Sources.ViewModels"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:TestingDeepRefresh.Sources.Converters">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <converters:StringPOCOToStringConverter x:Key="stringPOCOToString" />
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Padding="30,0"
            Spacing="25">
            <Image
                Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                HeightRequest="185"
                Aspect="AspectFit"
                SemanticProperties.Description="dot net bot in a race car number eight" />

            <CollectionView x:Name="stringVMCollection"
                BackgroundColor="Red"
                Margin="10"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                ItemsSource="{Binding MyStringVMs}">
                <CollectionView.Header>
                    <Label Text="My stringVMs :"/>
                </CollectionView.Header>
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewmodels:StringVM">
                        <Entry
                            MaxLength="30"
                            Placeholder="enter Name"
                            Text="{Binding Name}"
                            ReturnCommand="{Binding Source={Reference stringVMCollection}, Path=BindingContext.EditStringVMCommand}"
                            ReturnCommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                            />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
            <Button
                BackgroundColor="Aquamarine"
                Text="Update!"
                Command="{Binding UpdatingCommand}"/>
            <CollectionView
                BackgroundColor="Teal"
                Margin="10"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                ItemsSource="{Binding MyStrings}">
                <CollectionView.Header>
                    <Label Text="My Strings"/>
                </CollectionView.Header>
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:StringPOCO">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource stringPOCOToString}}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>                
            </CollectionView>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>

View csharp
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
  private DeepObservableCollection<StringPOCO> _myStrings = new();
  public DeepObservableCollection<StringPOCO> MyStrings => _myStrings;

  private ObservableCollection<StringVM> _myStringVMs = new();
  public ObservableCollection<StringVM> MyStringVMs => _myStringVMs;

  private static MainPage? _instance;
  public static MainPage? Instance => _instance;

  public ICommand UpdatingCommand => new Command(Update);
  public ICommand EditStringVMCommand => new Command<StringVM>(EditStringVM);

  public MainPage()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    BindingContext = this;

    _instance = this;

    _PopulateMyStringVMs();
  }

  private void _PopulateMyStringVMs()
  {
    Trace.WriteLine($"Calling {nameof(_PopulateMyStringVMs)}...");

    _myStringVMs.Clear();
    _myStringVMs.Add(StringVM.Create("One"));
    _myStringVMs.Add(StringVM.Create("Two"));
    _myStringVMs.Add(StringVM.Create("Three"));
  }

  private void Update(object o)
  {
    Trace.WriteLine($"Calling {nameof(Update)}...");

    foreach (var stringVM in _myStringVMs)
    {
      stringVM.UpdateAssociatedPOCO();
    }

    foreach (var stringPOCO in _myStrings)
      Trace.WriteLine(stringPOCO.DTO?.Data);
  }

  private void EditStringVM(StringVM stringVM)
  {
    Trace.WriteLine($"Calling {nameof(EditStringVM)}...");

    stringVM.UpdateAssociatedPOCO();
  }
}

ViewModel
public partial class StringVM : ObservableObject
{
  [ObservableProperty]
  string _name;

  public Guid ID { get; init; }

  public StringVM(string name, Guid id)
  {
    _name = name;
    ID=id;
  }

  public StringVM(string name)
  : this(name, Guid.NewGuid())
  { }

  public static StringVM Create(string name)
  {
    var poco = StringPOCO.Create(name);

    if (poco == default)
      return new StringVM(name);

    var mainPage = MainPage.Instance;
    if (mainPage != null)
    {
      mainPage.MyStrings.Add(poco);
    }

    return new StringVM(name, poco.ID);
  }

  public StringPOCO? GetAssociatedPOCO()
  {
    var mainPage = MainPage.Instance;
    if (mainPage == default)
      return default;

    return mainPage.MyStrings.FirstOrDefault(poco => poco.ID == ID);
  }

  public bool UpdateAssociatedPOCO()
  {
    var foundPOCO = GetAssociatedPOCO();
    if (foundPOCO?.DTO?.Data == default)
      return false;

    foundPOCO.DTO.Data = Name;
    return true;
  }
}

Model
public partial class StringPOCO : ObservableObject
{
  [ObservableProperty]
  StringDTO _dTO;

  public Guid ID { get; init; }

  public StringPOCO(StringDTO dto)
    : this(dto, Guid.NewGuid())
  { }

  public StringPOCO(StringDTO dto, Guid id)
  {
    DTO = dto;
    ID = id;
    dto.PropertyChanged += (sender, EventArgs) =>
    {
      OnPropertyChanged(nameof(DTO));
    };
  }

  public StringPOCO(string dtoAsString)
    : this(new StringDTO(dtoAsString))
  { }
  public static StringPOCO Create(string dtoAsString)
  {
    return new StringPOCO(dtoAsString);
  }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////

public partial class StringDTO : ObservableObject
{
  [ObservableProperty]
  string _data;

  public StringDTO(string data)
  {
    _data = data;
  }
}

The DeepObservableCollection is just an ObservableCollection that register on each of its items PropertyChanged event to call a Reset event. (took from this SO post) :
public class DeepObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
  where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
    {
      RegisterPropertyChanged(e.NewItems);
    }
    else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
    {
      UnRegisterPropertyChanged(e.OldItems);
    }
    else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace)
    {
      UnRegisterPropertyChanged(e.OldItems);
      RegisterPropertyChanged(e.NewItems);
    }

    base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
  }

  protected override void ClearItems()
  {
    UnRegisterPropertyChanged(this);
    base.ClearItems();
  }

  private void RegisterPropertyChanged(IList items)
  {
    foreach (INotifyPropertyChanged item in items)
    {
      if (item != null)
      {
        item.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(item_PropertyChanged);
      }
    }
  }

  private void UnRegisterPropertyChanged(IList items)
  {
    foreach (INotifyPropertyChanged item in items)
    {
      if (item != null)
      {
        item.PropertyChanged -= new PropertyChangedEventHandler(item_PropertyChanged);
      }
    }
  }

  private void item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    ///Launch an event Reset with name of property changed
    base.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
  }
}

With all this inner binding done, any change in MyStrings (model) collection's item's DTO.Data is to be reflected in my second CollectionView.
In order to properly display them, I use this Converter
Converter
public class StringPOCOToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object? Convert(object? value, Type targetType, object? parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    StringPOCO? stringPOCO = value as StringPOCO;
    StringDTO? stringDTO = stringPOCO?.DTO;
    if (stringDTO == null)
      return $"Fail to convert {value?.GetType().Name ?? $"NULL {nameof(value)}"} as a {nameof(StringPOCO)} to a string.";

    return stringDTO.Data;
  }

  public object? ConvertBack(object? value, Type targetType, object? parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}

This where things goes strange.
Any change to my 2nd and 3rd entry in MyStringsVM view model collection is reflected, but never the first one !??
When I change the corresponding Entry (text box) and commit it (Return keyboard pressed) in Two or Three in my first CollectionView (view model) I see them reflected
in my second CollectionView (model).
But any change in One doesn't get reflected, even if the model is correclty updated (As I spot them in debug logging via Trace.WriteLine(...) calls).
After putting a breakpoint in my Converter I see that on starting the application, it is called 9 times following this same scheme :
Converter is called with

a null value argument.
a StringPOCO value argument with "One" data.
a StringPOCO value argument with "One" data.
a null value argument.
a StringPOCO value argument with "Two" data.
a StringPOCO value argument with "Two" data.
a null value argument.
a StringPOCO value argument with "Three" data.
a StringPOCO value argument with "Three" data.

And I correctly see them reflected in UI :

One


Two


Three

When I change any of One, Two or Three in my first CollectionView (view model), after propagating update to my model and back to my view, the Converter is called exactly 4 times.
2 times with the corresponding "Two" StringPOCO value argument and 2 times with the corresponding "Three" StringPOCO value argument.
So the first corresponding "One" StringPOCO value parameter is never passed to the Converter !??
This explain why this first entry is never reflected back visually, but why the Converter misbehave this way ???
Thank for following me in this long post.

I can totally reproduce this issue. The interesting thing is that your code works as expected on Android only fails on Windows. You may file an issue on GitHub if you want.
The workaround I find, is to change the Binding expression in XAML (as well as some pieces of code in Converter). For example, if you try this,
Binding the DTO property,
<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:StringPOCO">
        <Label Text="{Binding DTO, Converter={StaticResource stringPOCOToString}}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

Then change the converter,
public object? Convert(object? value, Type targetType, object? parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    StringDTO? stringDTO = value as StringDTO;
    if (stringDTO == null)
        return $"Fail to convert value to a string.";
    return stringDTO.Data;
}

It works as expected.
Or even you could bind to DTO.Data, then you don't need a Converter any more.
...
<Label Text="{Binding DTO.Data}"/>
...


Thanks for your answer. For me the issue is always on the first Entry, no matter how many time I Edit it.
In this post example indeed I could bind directly to DTO or DTO.Data (and no issue anymore in this case). But in my real use case I have an ObservableCollection of interface typed objects. And since this interface has a default implemented property in it i need a converter (see this other SO post of mine for reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78776678/maui-binding-to-default-interface-property?noredirect=1#comment138890867_78776678)

I think you may raise an issue on GitHub as it only happens on Windows, while on Android it works as expected.
